# Display/hide div depending on device width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

Is it possible to hide a div with (or without) Bootstrap 4 if the screen width is over/under a specific value? Does it need javascript for that? 
More specifically, I'm looking for hiding a specific text (that I find useless on a mobile screen). I tried classes like "hidden-sm-up" but I couldn't make it work. Sorry if it's a basic question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

media queries in CSS are what you are looking for.

```
.mydiv{display:block; /*default behavior*/}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) { 
.mydiv{display:none; /*hide div on all screens with 700 and lower width*/}
 }
```

(try dragging the divider between js and outpuut block)
https://jsfiddle.net/qaabhmou/

more you can find here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Why the !important?

Comment: the truth is, it is not exactly necessary, but I was working on project, where were quite a few media queries and it was really messy ... sometimes I do it to be really sure this style will be there. I admit, that in simple example like this, it is not necessary.

Comment: deleted to prevent of some misleading of questioner, tanks for that

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if its use is controversial as far as accessibility anymore, but it is still black magic ;)